# HTML linking from different directories

Tags: php, html

I am working on a website. There are on every page equal navs. So I outsourced them into one PHP file where I echo the nav.

So the problem is the pathes are different because I have some files in subdirectories.

My file hierarchy looks like:
- index.php
- logic/
-- drawer.php
- account/
-- login.php

I include the `drawer.php` in `index.php` and `login.php`.
But when I'm linking from `index` to `login`, I have a different path as if linking from `login` to `index`.

Comment: Use absolute paths.  /root/  , ex: /var/www/login.php

Comment: When I make absulte pathes he writes me the whole address into to address bar. Then it looks like:  https://imgur.com/a/570bd

Comment: Please show us your attempt and we might be able to see where you're going wrong. Includes doesn't affect the url. Are you just trying to link to pages or use PHP's `include`?

Comment: If it is for links, you should prepend the links with a slash:: `href="/logic/drawer.php"` and so on. Starting a link with `/` will make the link relative from the document root. However, that's not "including" a file, that's linking to a file.

Comment: Thank you. I played a little bit with the links and I got it final to work.